# MySQL: Hundreds of tables or one big table?

Tags: mysql

I want to create a webpage where user can organize things they collect. As everyone collects something else I want to have the users create their own datamodell (with strict limitations). If two people are collection the same "things" they can share a datastructure.
My idea was to give every collection an ID and all the tables belonging to that collection will have the ID as a prefix.

```
Table: Collections
ID | Collection
 1 | Poststamps
 2 | Barbie Dolls

Table: 1_Base
ID | StampValue | StampPic
....

Table: 2_Base
ID | EAN | Pic
....
```

Thus I would create many tables as each user could in theory create their own collection. I could also use only one very big table and a mapping table. Example:

```
Table: Colleactions
ID | Collection
 1 | Poststamps
 2 | Barbie Dolls

Table: Mapping
fkCollection | FieldName    | Mapping
1            | DoubleField1 | StampValue
1            | BlobField1   | StampPic
2            | StringField1 | EAN
2            | BlobField1   | StampPic

Table: CollectionData
fkCollection | DoubleField1 | ... | DoubleField10 | StringField1 | ... | Stringfield10 | BlobField1 | ...
1            | 30           |     |               |              |     |               | ...        |
2            |              |     |               | 21312412414  |     |                | ...        |
```

Any other ideas?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Did you tried to create `VIEW`? Or to use `UNION` ?

Comment: as far as I know union doesn't work in MySQL... correct me if I am wrong please... don't know about the view though

Comment: Hi! i have not tested anything yet. I am planning the project. As far as I know UNION isn't working. VIEW would help in case of solution 2, one big table. Correct?

Comment: A VIEW is essentially a pre-prepared SELECT statement, which can be handy if you have a very large SELECT spaning multiple tables... It could help you in this case, yes, but I think a rethink of the table structure is needed first

Comment: That's what i am here for. I thought about this for some days and was not able to come up with something better.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From what I can see, your second way of attempting this is going to be the easiest way... your queries will be ten fold simpler to handle, and you wouldn't need to programmably create tables on the fly... so my suggestion would be to modify your second idea slightly... Just to clarify something also, A blob will slow down the query speed so I am changing the block to hold the source link to the image instead.

TABLE: `Collections`

```
ID| Collection
1 | Poststamps
2 | Barbie Dolls
```

Table: `CollectionData`

```
fkCollection | DataType    | VALUE  | FieldName  |
1            | Double      | 30     | StampID    |
1            | String      | London | StampName  |
1            | ImgSrc      | ../loc | StampPic   |
2            | String      | Ken    | BarbieName |
2            | ImgSrc      | ../loc | BarbiePic  |
```

Comment: Thanks! That is a brilliant idea. I could now normalize the table and have a fkDataType and a fkFieldName. Thanks again!